# Opencart shop not loading correctly after hosting transfer

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have transferred my online shop from 1and1 to 123-reg, and it now doesn't load. The URL in question is http://www.luof.co.uk/shop

The static HTML pages are working fine (e.g. the homepage)

Here is what I did to transfer the shop over:

- Backed up the database on 1and1
- Downloaded all the files and uploaded them to the new server
- Changed the "a" record accordingly
- Imported the database onto 123-reg
- Changed config file settings

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of the time that php tags or code show in the browser it means that the server does not have PHP enabled, look for a setting to tick in the admin interface (I am not familiar with 123 reg hosting) or contact 123 reg support

Comment: i think you are right, I tried a phpinfo(); and came up with the same thing, will let you know :) thanks for the pointer!